JSON data transformation of various scructure into unified one via JOLT
I have valious formats of incoming JSON from 3rd parties that I need to process in unified manner. Considering the data structure is not normalized, I could not apply unified logic of data processing. To achieve that I'm seeking for data formatting into single format before processing.
Source 1:
{
  "fieldName": "status",
  "oldValue": "Open",
  "newValue": "Closed"
}

Source 2:
{
  "fieldName": "status",
  "oldValue": {
    "name": "Open"
  },
  "newValue": {
    "name": "Closed"
  }
}

Source 3:
{
   "fieldName": "reason",
   "oldValue": null,
   "newValue": {
      "name": "Requirements changed"
   }
}

Source 4:
{
   "fieldName": "advertise",
   "oldValue": true,
   "newValue": false
}

In result transformation I would like to have the following (combined for all sources):
{
   "status"|"reason"|"advertise": {
      "oldValue": {
         "value": "Open"|null|true
      },
      "newValue": {
         "value": "Closed"|"Requirements changed"|false
      }
   }
}

I'm struggling with various combinations of shift and default but could not achieve the transformation. I tried to build JOLT specification that makes this transformation (see example below), however I'm unable to put different field structure (simple value vs object) into unified format.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fieldName": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,oldValue)": "&1.oldValue",
          "@(2,newValue)": "&1.newValue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Sample of code (Java) to reproduce the problem
package org.example;

import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Chainr;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        var spec = read("src/main/resources/spec.json");
        var chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(JsonUtils.jsonToList(spec));

        var example1 = read("src/main/resources/example1.json");
        var example2 = read("src/main/resources/example2.json");
        var example3 = read("src/main/resources/example3.json");
        var example4 = read("src/main/resources/example4.json");

        for (String source: List.of(example1, example2, example3, example4)) {
            System.out.println("===\nSource \n" + source);
            var transformedSource = chainr.transform(JsonUtils.jsonToMap(source));

            System.out.println("\nAfter transformation \n" +
                    JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedSource));
        }
    }

    private static String read(String path) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    }
}

You also need the following dependencies to achieve data transformation
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

Any thoughts how to make it possible?
Thanks in advance!

The following spec should work for all the scenarios:
[
 
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "oldValue": {
        "name": {
          "@": "@(3,fieldName).oldValue.value"
        },
        "*": {
          "@1": "@(3,fieldName).oldValue.value"
        }
      },
      "newValue": {
        "name": {
          "@": "@(3,fieldName).newValue.value"
        },
        "*": {
          "@1": "@(3,fieldName).newValue.value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "oldValue": {
          "value": null
        },
        "newValue": {
          "value": null
        }
      }
    }
  }

]


Hi @samsal77, thank you for your help! Any ideas how to update the specification to  transform such cases as well?
{   "fieldName": "status",   "oldValue": {     "name": "Open",     "label": "alt"   } }
For now it transforms into this
{   "status" : {     "oldValue" : {       "value" : [ "Open", {         "name" : "Open",         "label" : "alt"       } ]     },     "newValue" : {       "value" : [ "Closed", {         "name" : "Closed",         "label" : "alt"       } ]     }   } }
Thanks!

Hi, Now you are talking about a very moving target where the value field is not just single value but an array as well. It doesnt mean it cant be done but it will over complicate the spec which makes it hard to maintain in the future. What you need is  an Avro schema checker. Basically you define how your Json schema looks like using Avro  for each possible input and when you get the input you validate against each Avro schema and if it passes  you apply the proper json transformation. You can make this dynamic by storing each transformation against its avro schema in DB table.

More straightforward option would be
[
  { //handles null cases only through prefixing by the ~ operator 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "~*V*": "null" //convert the value into "null" if it's null
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": { //separate the cases for attributes of "name" vs. the others  
      "*V*": { //represents *Values
        "null": "@2,fieldName.&1.v&(1,2)",
        "name": { "@": "@3,fieldName.&2.v&(2,2)" }, //stands for the objects 
        "*": { "@1": "@3,fieldName.&2.v&(2,2)" } //stands for the plain attributes
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi Barbaros, I like your solution but it produces string "null" vs null. This could present problem when parsing when null is expected, no?

Oh yes, Hi @samsal77 , thanks for the good catch !

Hi @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for your input, but it does not guarantee availability of  "value" after transformation. It may keep "name" inside of "old(new)Value" instead.
This source describes what I mean:
{   "fieldName": "reason",   "oldValue": null,   "newValue": {     "name": "Requirements changed"   } }

Hi @AntonRusakou you're welcome, just fixed the issue
